# items.map: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-typescript, ionic-react

I'm trying to learn Ionic React with Typescript by creating a simple app for myself.

At this point 'I'm trying to dynamically populate an IonSegment from an array, the relevant code looks like this:

```
const [items, setItems] = useLocalStorage([{ id: 0, value: 'Item 0' }, { id: 1, value: 'Item 1' }, { id: 1, value: 'Item 1' }], [{ id: 0, value: 'An Error Occurred' }]);

....

<IonSegment color="brand" onIonChange={ ....... } value={sensor} id="segSensor">
            {items.map(item => {
              return (
                <IonSegmentButton key={item.id}>
                  <IonLabel>{item.value}</IonLabel>
                </IonSegmentButton>
              )
            })}
</IonSegment>
```

This fails to compile with the output:

> Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

So, I understand that item needs to have a type declared, but I've tried the following without success:

```
{items.map(item:any => {
              return (

{items.map(<any>item => {
              return (
```

How do I declare the type for item?

Thanks

Comment: Which `useLocalStorage` hook are you using? [This one](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage)? Does it provide TypeScript typings?

Comment: type Item =  { id: number, value: string } , use it instead of any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well its simple, you have to enclose your input in parenthesis as

```
items.map((item: any) => {})
```

Another thing that you can do is go in your `tsconfig.json` file and set `noImplicityAny` to false. This will stop TypeScript from yelling at you if something has an implicit `any` type.

Comment: I'd read about the noImplicitAny flag but figured I'd leave it as is inorder to force me to learn things like this.

Answer (score 3):

`items.map((item: any) => { ...`

Probably the problem is in useLocalStorage type too, maybe you have to create a type/interface for your initial state

`useLocalStorage<MyLocalStorageType>( ...`

Like that you can use the full power of TS

Comment: Thanks for the response. I marked @raja as the correct answer since he posted first.

Comment: No problem mate

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the paranteses in the arrow function when declaring a type:

```js
{items.map((item: any) => {
              return (
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I marked @raja as the correct answer since he posted first.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to type on the set function:

Outside the function:

```
interface ItemType {
id: number;
value: string;
}
```

Then you can:

```
const [items, setItems] = useLocalStorage<ItemType[]>([{ id: 0, value: 'Item 0'...
```

With this, typescript will know the typer for each item, and you can use the intellisense to access each item properties.